VAE with different input shapes and output shape equal to input shape
I'm trying to create a Variational AutoEncoder with the following charateristics:

input: matrices of different shape (not squared)
output: each output instance shape must match the input instance shape
Not applying any preprocessing operations on data like cropping or resizing
Possibly not applying strong postprocessing on VAE's output

my solution is a model like the following (simplified)
# Encoder
Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1)
Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1)
Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1)

# Latent space
mu = nn.Conv2d(128, latent_dim, kernel_size=1)
logvar = nn.Conv2d(128, latent_dim, kernel_size=1)
latent_out = nn.Conv2d(latent_dim, 128, kernel_size=1)

# Decoder
nn.ConvTranspose2d(128, 64, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1)
nn.ConvTranspose2d(64, 32, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1)
nn.ConvTranspose2d(32, 1, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1)

# Shape adjust (operation done in the decode function where I pass the input shapes from the forward)
F.interpolate(decoder_output, size=(input_h, input_w), mode='bilinear', align_corners=False)

This code actually works and recreate an output of the same shape of the input, but my concern is the latent space variables mu and logvar have shapes (1, latent_dim, floor(input_h/8), floor(input_w/8)) this can cause problems when I will use the model to extract the embedding of a matrix?

"this can cause problems when I will use the model to extract the embedding of a matrix?" Are you asking us or telling us? If you're telling us, then what's your question?
